# fail to retrieve record in exec function with php variable

Tags: php, curl, exec

I have code that retrieve mac address from machine whose ip address is matched. IP address is getting from database.
My problem is that I am unable to retrieve mac address with $ip variable.

```
$ip = "192.168.1.45";

$mac_id = exec('/usr/bin/curl http://$ip/mac_id.php');
```

but if I pass below line then this will give mac address for given directly added ip.

```
$mac_id = exec('/usr/bin/curl http://192.168.1.45/mac_id.php');
```

My question is why $ variable is not working with exec function ?

Comment: While you get reply. But one thing want to add that PHP not parse variable in single quoted string. Either you need to use double quoted string or append variable with dot like @Muhammad did in his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$mac_id = exec('/usr/bin/curl http://'.$ip.'/mac_id.php');